# Update row values in table does not work

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update values of a table if data exist. if not, create a new one.

The code connects to database, then takes the form data send by post method of an html. Once data has been stored in variables, set the search I want obtain.

Please, I don't know where is the error, I spent 3 entire days to know what is the problem with this.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php
$host_db = "host";
$user_db = "user";
$pass_db = "passwd";
$db_name = "database";
$tbl_name = "table";

$conexion = new mysqli($host_db, $user_db, $pass_db, $db_name);

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("conexion error: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

$data1=$_POST['data1'];
$data2=$_POST['data2'];
$data3=$_POST['data3'];


$search = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name
WHERE data1 = '$data1' ";
$result = $conexion->query($search);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

if ($count == 1) {
    echo "exist";
    $id=$row['ID'];
    $query = "UPDATE $tbl_name
        SET data1 ='$data1',
        data2 ='$data2',
        data3 = '$data3',
        WHERE ID = '$id'";

    if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "updated data";
    }else {
    echo "error updating data";
    }
}else{
    echo "does not exist";
    $query = "INSERT INTO $tbl_name (data1, data2, data3)
       VALUES ('$data1', '$data2', '$data3')";
    if ($conexion->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "data saved";
    }else {
        echo "error saving data";
    }
}
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO $tbl_name (data1, data2, data3)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE data1 = values(data1), data2 = values(data2), data3 = values(data3);
```

For this to work, you need a unique index or constraint on `data1`:

```
create unique index idx_t_data1 on $tbl_name(data1)
```

This has multiple advantages over your approach.  First, the unique index makes the database in charge of data integrity (the uniqueness of `data1`).  The database will do this for inserts and updates, regardless of where they are done.

Second, your code has a timing issue, so it might fail if two threads are attempting to insert the same value at about the same time.

Third, the `?` are placeholders for parameters.  You cannot parameterize the table name, but you can parameterize the values.  This is a good habit -- MySQL can cache the query plan so queries run faster, it saves you from unexpected syntax errors, and it makes the code less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.